# Trying to run Java7 Hello World Project from command line with maven

Tags: java, maven

Trying to run Java7 Hello World Project from command line with maven.. If I run the code from within eclipse my project runs ok but if I try to do a "mvn packege" package I get the following error..

Here is my source:

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!, Tesing Java 7" );
        printDay("Wednesday");
    }

    public static void printDay(String dayOfWeek) {
        switch (dayOfWeek) 
        {
            case "Sunday": System.out.println("Dimanche"); break;
            case "Monday": System.out.println("Lundi"); break;
            case "Tuesday": System.out.println("Mardi"); break;
            case "Wednesday": System.out.println("Mercredi"); break;
            case "Thursday": System.out.println("Jeudi"); break;
            case "Friday": System.out.println("Vendredi"); break;
            case "Saturday": System.out.println("Samedi"); break;

            default: System.out.println("Error: '"+ dayOfWeek +"' is not a day of the week"); break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.smith</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestJava7</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>TestJava7</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here IS THE ERROR:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/jsmith/Documents/workspace-juno/TestJava7/src/main/java/org/smith/TestJava7/App.java:[16,13] error: strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.5
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.169s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jan 16 09:48:26 EST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/100M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project TestJava7: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/jsmith/Documents/workspace-juno/TestJava7/src/main/java/org/smith/TestJava7/App.java:[16,13] error: strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set version of source and target for the comiler plugin:

[http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Error is clearly saying:

```
strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.5
```

You need to configure `maven-compiler-plugin` to point to JDK 7, by default it will point to 1.5 or 1.6

Try [Here for more information](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/usage.html) on how to configure the same.

Answer (score 1):

Add the maven plugin to your POM.xml,clean and run again ..

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.7</source>
    <target>1.7</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```