# Maven error when compiling String.format

Tags: java, maven

I'm running into a problem where the Maven compile process seems to throw an error whenever I try to use `String.format` in my code.

I'm using Maven 3.0.4 with Java 1.7.0_25. I created a test project like this:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -groupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=testapp
```

I then changed the main method located in `src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/App.java` into:

```
package com.mycompany.app;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( String.format("Hello World!") );
    }
}
```

Notice the `String.format` in the `System.out.println` call.

When doing a `mvn compile`, I'm now getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project testapp: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/me/projects/java/testapp/src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/App.java:[11,34] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

I'm not sure how to fix this. For completeness, this is my generated `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>testapp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>testapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**UPDATE**

Maven version info:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_AU, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.5.0-37-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: Just as a thought, can you use `StringBuilder` in the code? Not to try to fix the problem - I'm just interested as to whether that's recognized. Because both `StringBuilder` and `String.format` were introduced in Java 1.5.

Comment: When I change the line inside System.out.println to StringBuilder("Hello World!").reverse() I get the same error.

Comment: Okay - it sounds like Maven is compiling against JDK 1.4 or earlier then. I haven't used Maven in a long time, but see if specifying something like `-v` on the command line shows more about which JRE it's using to run to start with.

Comment: I've installed Maven through apt-get: `sudo apt-get install maven` which installed Maven 3. The other option was to do `sudo apt-get install maven2` which obviously would install Maven 2. I was assuming that Maven 3 was using a recent version of Java but like you said, it looks like it doesn't

Comment: I've updated the question with the Maven version output.

Comment: The answer on this question seems to fix the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361056/trying-to-run-java7-hello-world-project-from-command-line-with-maven?rq=1 I don't understand why this doesn't work out of the box.

Comment: So just specifying `-source` and `-target` fixes the problem? That's odd, as I didn't think they changed the API being used. Still, you probably wanted to specify them anyway to be honest :)

Comment: I actually had to add the entire plugin section of which the `source` and `target` are the attributes. The generated `pom.xml` didn't seem to include this plugin definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this to the pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>    
</build>
```

I think by default maven try to compile your code to be compatible with 1.4.

Check this link for more info: 
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Comment: Umm ... according to http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/, the default is 1.5 not 1.4.  However, it is (IMO) a good idea for a POM file to specify the Java version anyway.

Comment: Hmmm, I think it depends of the maven-compiler-plugin version. In his example he is using 2.0.2 version (a default version because he doesn't specify any in the pom.xml).